# Match length of two unequal arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, max, size

Suppose I have 3 arrays of different length:
A[1 2 3 4 5 6]; B[1 2 4], C[0 1 5 6]

the MAXIMUM length the three arrays is 6.
So I want B and C to have 6 elements too. Furthermore, the last "filled" elements of new array should be the last element of the original array

At the end, new B should look like [1 2 4 4 4 4], C should look like [0 1 5 6 6 6],  how do I implement this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using MATLAB's indexing operators. If you assign to elements past the `end` of an array, MATLAB will grow the array. For vectors (as in this case), you only need to specify a single subscript because the direction to extend the array is not ambiguous.

I'd do it like this - this doesn't assume that you know up-front which of the arrays is the largest. I'm using `numel` to compute the number of elements in each vector. I'm also relying on the fact that for one of the arrays, `end+1:maxLen` is an empty range, so no modifications are made in that case.

```
maxLen = max([numel(A), numel(B), numel(C)]);
A(end+1:maxLen) = A(end)
B(end+1:maxLen) = B(end)
C(end+1:maxLen) = C(end)
```